# Scrapy dynamic file name based on timestamp for the logfile

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy and logging the results to a log file using the LOG_FILE= in settings.py.
However what I want is that each time I run the spider it should log to a different filename based on the timestamp.
Is it possible to achieve this by doing some setting in settings.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
import time
LOG_FILE = str(int(time.time()))
```

---

`settings.py` is a python script, you can write any python code in it.